# JsonResult in MVC behaving wired

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

One of the action method, am returning `JsonResult` upon some failure condition like below

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Action1(Demo d)
{
   var result =  //call WEB API service endpoint
   if(result.ErrorCode == "Success")
    {
        //send 200 status code
    }
   else
   {
       //log the error result.ErrorMessage
       return Json(new MyError {Message = result.ErrorMessage});
   }   
}
```

This action method is called in Angular controller and it displays the same error message in UI.

problem is that, when tested in local deployment I could very well see the error message in UI but when deployed in Dev/QA the error message is not coming at all.

Strange fact is that, exact error message getting logged in log file for both Dev/QA but that error message is not coming in `HttpResponse`

I tried debugging in browser developer and could see that in `local` environment the Angular `response` object getting filled with a JSON object like `{Message: "the message", errorcode: code}` but in `Dev/QA` the object becoming `null`

if I track the request/response in Fiddler the only difference I see between local and Dev/QA environment is Response `Content-Type:` header which in local `application/json, charset: utf-8` but in Dev/QA it's `text/html`.

Any idea what's going wrong here?

Comment: Are you sure that the action is returning the error and not the 200 status code part? Returning `Json(...)` should explicitly set the content type header to tell the client to accept JSON.

Comment: @DavidG, absolutely sure ... as I did verified it in log file, browser developer window and in Fiddler too. I kind a exhausted with my ideas and so thought of asking the same here.

Comment: Hmm, you don't show the logging above so where is that from?

Comment: @DavidG, it's using `NLog` and not custom logging mechanism

Comment: How about your `[HttpGet]` methods, do they return correct content type?

Comment: What browsers? We were seeing some issues in Firefox if we didn't explicitly add the `Accept` header to expect json.

Comment: @ps2goat, did tested in IE and chrome .. in both cases could see the same behavior

Comment: @MatForsberg, didn't get you sorry ... do you want me to post the error log code or asking me to check the error log?

Comment: I was wondering what the error message is. But also you say the error message is always the same. could the error code change. you are only logging the message but not the code

Comment: @MatForsberg, No, it's a hardcoded error message for a specific condition. I am logging both error code and message. what am saying is that the error message I expect to see can be seen in log but it's not flowing to Angular controller method